# Folding from occurrence to next; two or more comments

Tags: folding, filetype-tex

I wanted to fold my LaTeX document and found this:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130586/vim-nice-folding-function

(Which seems to indicate that folding has been removed from Latex-Box?) That takes care of environments. But I am still missing two functions, which I was hoping might be added to the code referred to, namely:

- folding from every occurrence of `\somecommand` to one line above the next;
- folding two or more subsequent commented out lines.

Comment: [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) provides a reasonably nice folding function that provides folding for commented out lines (with `let g:vimtex_fold_comments = 1`. It does not provide the folding between occurences of `\somecommand`, but I don't really understand why you would want that.

Comment: Because my document consists of parts preceeded by a \comment macro. Thanks.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg, % fakesection does the job. Is there a way to refresh the folds without exiting and reopening?